# How to describe mouse clicks in markdown?

Tags: markdown, mouse, documentation

For many documentations it is necessary to describe a series of mouse clicks.

I have seen things like:
`File -> Preferences -> Settings`

Questions:

- How should I describe a series of mouse clicks in markdown (is there a commonly accepted way?)
- How should one describe right- and double-clicks?
- If there are different versions, what are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should not make unique chains of mouse-clicks. The same way that left-clicking is commonly used as a "Select" option (and is instinctively the default mouse click), you should define the behavior of your mouse-clicks if you want them to have unique functionality. I.e right mouse button for "More Options", middle mouse button for "Other Functionality".

If that doesn't suffice your question, I would suggest something like:

`File -> (RMB) Preferences -> (MMB) Settings`

or

`File -> (Right-click) Preferences -> Special Settings`